# C - a certain function in my program wont work with either returning an integer nor using a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, return-value, implementation

This is my first time posting of this forum and I'm doing is just because of this problem. I've been working on a program for a while(just for fun) and to make things simple for my self I used loads of global variables, but now I've been trying to make the individual functions more independent and flexible. A certain function is giving a a lot of issues for some reason.

```
int which_move(int ac,int bc,int cc){

    int illcheck;
    int ill_done;
    int ill_pos;
    int true_move;

    true_move=3;
    ill_done=-1;

    for(u=6;u>=0;u--){

        ill_pos=ert-1;
        illcheck=0;

        for(y=0;y<ill_len[u];y++){

            if(buff[ill_pos]==ill_move[u][y]){

                ++illcheck;

                if(ill_pos==0)
                    ill_pos=100;
                --ill_pos;

                if(illcheck==ill_len[u]){
                    ill_done=u;
                    break;
                }
            }

            else
                break;
        }

        if(ill_done!=-1)
            break;
    }

    if(ac==1||ill_done==1||ill_done==2||ill_done==6)
        true_move=0;

    if(bc>2)
        true_move=1;

    if(cc>2)
        true_move=2;

    if(ill_done==0||ill_done==3||ill_done==4)
        true_move=4;

    if(ill_done==5)
        true_move=5;

   return true_move;
}
```

and this is how i call the function:

```
int open_move;
open_move=which_move(acheck,bcheck,ccheck);
```

and `open_move` never match `true_move`.

I've tried to convert to something like this

```
int which_move(int *true_move,int ac,int bc,int cc)
```

and remove `int true_move;` and the return of `return true_move;` and implement the function like this:

```
int open_move;
which_move(open_move,acheck,bcheck,ccheck);
```

still i get it to work.

I've googled til chrome starts lagging because of too many tabs open and tried every trick I can find, but I'm not getting any wiser. Please help me with what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks from a hobbyist.

Comment: Describing the problem in words and snippets is not very clear. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also give the exact expected result vs actual result. An MVE means smallest amount of complete code that someone else can run exactly as is to reproduce the exact problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Have you tried using a debugger to single-step through the code and help you identify the source of the issues?